# What is the academic degree of medical school graduate after 6 years of study, plus 1 year intern?

Tags: degree

What is the equivalent of medical degrees to Bachelor, Master and PhD?
Calculating points for Canadian Express Entry program. On education section, they have only these degrees - Bachelor, Master, PhD. Not sure which is the correct for Doctor of Medicine.

Answer (score 3):

Huh. According to [this table (PDF)](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/guides/pdf/ECA_table_EN.pdf), an entry-to-practice degree that requires licensure is credited the same as a master's level, 23 points.

> University-level credential at the Master’s level OR an
>   entry-to-practice professional degree. CIC only accepts as an
>   entry-to-practice professional degree, those degrees issued in
>   relation to an occupation listed at NOC Skill level A and for which
>   licensing by a provincial regulatory body is required.

This section includes:

various master's, medicine, veterinary medicine, dentistry, podiatry, chiropractic medicine, optometry, law, and pharmacy.